# Does the jQuery .not selector work with .delegate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to make an Ajax call on all `<a>` elements inside the id `#filter` which don't have the class `.noAjax` and somehow i can't get it to work. could someone have a look at my syntax please?

```
$("#filter").not($("a.noAjax")).delegate("ul#portfolio-list li a", "click", function() {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        location.hash = "#/" + this.pathname;
    } else {
        location.hash = this.pathname;
    }
    return false;
});
```

when i try to just use `a` or `a.ajax` (which i of course added before trying) as the selector for `.delegate` nothing works at all. with the jquery above the ajax works, but it tries to load content even when i click a link with `a.noAjax`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector instead:

```
$("#filter").delegate("ul#portfolio-list li a:not(.noAjax)","click",function() {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        location.hash = "#/" + this.pathname;
    } else {
        location.hash = this.pathname;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Or you could delegate to the `ul` element instead, since it's using a unique ID, for improved selector performance:

```
$("#portfolio-list").delegate("li a:not(.noAjax)", ...);
```

Comment: thanks to all your answers. but whats the differnce between using .not and :not if there is any?

Comment: @tobias: `.not` is a filter method which runs on an already obtained set of elements. `:not` is a selector which runs during the query for the elements.  `delegate()` doesn't run the selector until the click event, which is why you need the selector instead of the method.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$("#filter").not($("a.noAjax")).
```

Should be on the `a` elements, like this:

```
$("#filter a").not("a.noAjax")
```

Or, what you're *really* after:

```
$("#portfolio-list").delegate("li a:not(.noAjax)", "click", function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first part to this:

```
$("#filter a").not($(".noAjax")).del...
```

The other way will select all elements in `#filter` that are not `a.noAjax` (including non-anchor tags).