# Redirect events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation where some content is being delivered in a DIV, and I want to intercept an "off-click" of the DIV event.

For example:

```
<div id="whole_page">
  ...some buttons
  <div id="cont">
    ...some more buttons
    <div id="cont_deliv">
      ..finish button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So.. once the "cont_deliv" div is loaded, clicks to buttons outside that div - or even a page change attempt if possible go to a Javascript function that ..say.. throws up an alert('Are you sure you want to abort') type function.

Comment: Check jQuery `closest()` function

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Are you sure you want to abort"; }` will alert any time a user is leaving your page. If you want to capture all clicks (even non-redirecting ones) that aren't on your div, use event delegation and possibly the `:not()` selector http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216306/does-the-jquery-not-selector-work-with-delegate